# how disccover which selenium and chromedriver is used during polymer test

Tags: selenium, polymer, selenium-chromedriver, polymer-cli

I get this error when running "Cannot establish new session" when I run "polymer test --skip-selenium-install"

```
error: [cli.main]   Error: {"value":{"stacktrace":"org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Cannot establish new session\nBuild info: version: \u00273.8.1\u0027, revisi
on: \u00276e95a6684b\u0027, time: \u00272017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z\u0027\nSystem info: host: \u0027WDU8L0001186\u0027, ip: \u002710.244.11.110\u0027, os.name: \u0027Windows 7\u0
027, os.arch: \u0027x86\u0027, os.version: \u00276.1\u0027, java.version: \u00271.8.0_172\u0027\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.server
.ServicedSession$Factory.apply(ServicedSession.java:261)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11(ActiveSessionFactory.java:167)\r\n\tat
```

...

```
e":"Cannot establish new session\nBuild info: version: \u00273.8.1\u0027, revision: \u00276e95a6684b\u0027, time: \u00272017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z\u0027\nSystem info: host: \u00
27WDU8L0001186\u0027, ip: \u002710.244.11.110\u0027, os.name: \u0027Windows 7\u0027, os.arch: \u0027x86\u0027, os.version: \u00276.1\u0027, java.version: \u00271.8.0_172\u0027
\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown","error":"session not created"},"status":33}
    at C:\Users\D-CA69TO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\web-component-tester\runner\steps.js:170:27
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\D-CA69TO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\web-component-tester\runner\steps.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

By googling around I saw that this might be caused by wrong combination of Selenium, ChromeDriver and Chrome. Well, my Chrome is Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (32-bit) but how can I check which is the Selenium and ChromeDriver been used? Honestly, I don't remenber I installed them so I assume polymer-cli did this for me somehow.

*** Edited after Corey's suggestion

```
C:\>chromedriver -v
'chromedriver' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: You can refer this link https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. You mean, should I post this question there? If so, how? At the bottom I see "StackOverflow chromedriver posts" so I assum I am posting my question here correctly. My straight question is: how disccover which selenium and chromedriver is used during polymer test? I understand it is the first step: discover which Selenium and ChromeDriver version been used during Polymer Test before reporting an issue.

Comment: install chromedriver

Answer (score 1):

to get the chromedriver version: `chromedriver -v`

if you have the selenium python bindings installed, you can check the version with: `python -c "import selenium; print(selenium.__version__)"`

for example, in a shell you can do:

```
$ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 2.36 (0)
$ python -c "import selenium; print(selenium.__version__)"
3.11.0
```

Comment: I didn't installed directly chromedriver (please, see my edition on botoom of my question). I am sure polymer test uses WCT and WCT uses Selenium and Chromedriver behind scene but I didn't manage how figure out which version is used.